# Chart js doesn't show data

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying  to show data comes from controller in my View using chart js; Now I'm getting just the template of the chart but no data diplayed.
this is the method in controller:

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> EachDay(DateTime from, DateTime thru)
        {  
            for (var day =from.Date; day.Date <= thru.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
                yield return day;
        }
        public ActionResult Dashboard()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Dashboard(DateTime ddebut, DateTime dfin)
        {
            Réception_phosphateEntities db = new Réception_phosphateEntities();

            List<Réception_camions> listréception = db.Réception_camions.ToList();         
            List<Wagons> listwg = db.Wagons.ToList();               
            List<Consommation> co = db.Consommation.ToList();

            List<Double?> stock = new List<Double?>();
            List<DateTime?> dates = new List<DateTime?>();

             foreach (DateTime date in EachDay(ddebut, dfin))
            {
                var stk = listwg.Where(x => x.Date_culbutage <= date.Date).Select(x => x.Poids).Sum()
                    + listréception.Where(x => x.Date_d_arrivée <= date.Date).Select(x => (double)x.Poids_cam).Sum()
                    - co.Where(x => x.Date_consommation <= date.Date).Select(x => x.Qtité_consommée).Sum();

                dates.Add(date);
                stock.Add(stk);
                return View();
            }


            ViewBag.date = dates;
            ViewBag.stk = stock;
            return View();
        }
```

and in my View  I have this code:

```js
        var stock=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.stk));
        var dates=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.date));
        var ctx = $("#bar_chart");
        var bacChart = new Chart(ctx,{
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: dates,
                datasets: [{
                    label: "bar chart example",
                    data: stock,
                   
                }]
            }
        })
```

```html
 <form action="/Home/Dashboard" method='post'>

        <a>Date début</a>   <input type="date" name="ddebut" style="height:25px">

        <a>Date fin</a>  <input type="date" name="dfin" style="height:25px">
        <input type="submit" value="MAJ">
        
    </form>

    <div id="chat_container">
        <canvas id="bar_chart"></canvas>
    </div>
```

I didn't find where is the problem, thanks for your help.

Comment: Any errors on the console?

Comment: No error, but I tryied with a fixed data in View: `labels: ["January", "Feburary", "March"] /*dates*/,`  and  `data: [15, 20, 35] /*stock*/,` it works

Comment: You are returning the view inside the loop before setting the viewbaga items. Remove the `return View()` from the loop.

Comment: That's it, thanks @Shyju